# converting float to unsigned char in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have designed a filter in the form of a horizontal 1D vector using OpenCV and C++. The vector consists of float data. The original uchar data of the grayscale image is multiplied with this float vector as a 1 dimensional window to obtain the result. However, I am not getting proper results.

When the vector elements are multiplied with the image pixel values, the exceed the range 0-255 and I think this is causing problems.

Is there any way to typecast this float data into uchar to get proper results?

I'm using `Img.at<uchar> = (uchar)(floatVector)` right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to type cast after you have multiplied...so convert your `uchar` image matrix to `CV_32FC1` (since you say its grayscale image so channel = 1)....do the convolution of the image with your filter then type cast the values to `uchar`for displaying may be..

Comment: Thanks. that worked. However, I had to normalize the values of the output matrix in the range 0 to 255 to get the correct result. :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity ...how did you convolve the 1D filter with the 2D image? row wise or height wise?

Comment: convolve the 1d filter with horizontal pixels, den vertical pixels. and u r done :)

Comment: by convolving the horizontal pix if u mean raster scanning the 1D filter array over the image then you have already altered the image b4 u convolve it with vertical pix...or is it that u stretched d 2D image  into a 1D and convolved that with the 1D filter array...hope u dnt mind me asking u these details...!!

Comment: actually I implemented the recursive gaussian kernel by R.Deriche and then utilized the separable kernel property.

Answer (score 0):

You want to carry out the multiplication in the float type, and only at the end, convert back to unsigned char. Don't forget to also have your float vector normalized (all values add up to 1)

So basically you want

Data.at(coordinates) = (unsigned char)
(floatVector(0)*(Data.at(coord0) + ... + FloatVector(last)*Data.at(coordLast))